# Dotnet test routine fail

Tags: c#, automated-tests, asp.net-core-mvc, dotnet-httpclient, .net-3.0

I got an dotnet project and i was building an implementation test routine

Here is my code:

Base->BaseProject->Controllers->SensorController

```
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class SensorController : Controller
    {
        private readonly SensorContext _context;

        public SensorController(SensorContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        
        [HttpGet("api/")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Sensor>>> GetTodoItems()
        {
            return await _context.Sensor.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
```

And in my TestProject, I got this:

Base->TestProject->Fixtures->TestContext

```
    public class TestContext
    {
        public HttpClient Client { get; private set; }
        private TestServer _server;
        public TestContext()
        {
            SetupClient();
        }
        private void SetupClient()
        {
            _server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>());
            Client = _server.CreateClient();
        }
    }
```

Base->TestProject->SensorApiTest.cs

```
    public class SensorApiTest
    {
        private readonly TestContext _testContext;
        public SensorApiTest()
        {
            _testContext = new TestContext();
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task Values_Get_ReturnsOkResponse()
        {
            var response = await _testContext.Client.GetAsync("/Sensor/api");
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
        }
    }
```

If i run the base project and send requests using insominia, i got the responses just fine. But running the TestProject with dotnet test return an 404 error.
The dependencies off the project are working fine, i dont know why this do not run.

Can anyone help me? Thanks